# Problem with playing mp4 video on Android

Tags: android

I wrote a small application that downloads an mp4 video from the net and after sometime plays it.
The video is seen for about 1.5 minutes but after that it freezes surprisingly.
Logcat shows:

```
07-11 18:35:22.132: ERROR/PlayerDriver(53): Content is truncated.
07-11 18:35:22.132: ERROR/MediaPlayer(867): error (1, 31)
07-11 18:35:22.132: ERROR/MediaPlayer(867): Error (1,31)
```

and that's it.
This phenomenon is consistent with any content I play, so I guess the problem is not with the content itself.
Does anyone know the nature of this problem?

Thanks,
Eyal